# error al imprimir variable de un campo de una matriz tridimensional en C

Tags: c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

omitir lo comentado por favor, el error se observa en la ultima fila al ejecutarlo y al inicio demuestro q el campo si es '00000'

Comment: Bienvenido. Mira como crear un [mre]. Además el código va como texto.